# ¿Como puedo obtener los getters de unos setters que estan en otro metodo?

Tags: java

Necesito obtener los getters en el main de los setters que estan en el metodo set pero no tengo mucha idea de como poder hacerlo.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Nombre: ");
        System.out.println("Fecha: ");
    }

   private void set() {
       ejemplo ej = new ejemplo();
       ej.setNombre("juan perez");
       ej.setFecha("01-01-2021");
   }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: No entiendo bien que queres hacer.. pero ahi estas creando dos clases ejemplo completamente distintas.. te das cuenta de eso?

Comment: no @Dramaturgo.. eso va a crear los datos en otra clase distinta a la principal....ç

Comment: Pues todo depende de cómo declares la clase Ejemplo y en qué package esté.

Comment: una forma de verlo es que `ej` noesissste fuera de `set()` fijate este código con imágenes https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/1423096 . basicamente a `ej` podrías crearlo en main y se lo pasas a set para que le de valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de dos maneras ,la primera es que tu método set reciba como parámetro un objeto y mediante sus setters,darle nuevos valores y luego imprimirlo con getters, la otra seria haciendo todo dentro del metodo,crear instancia, setters, getters y prints, aunque de esta forma no obtendras de nuevo esa instancia creada

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ejemplo ej = new Ejemplo();
    set(ej);

    System.out.println(ej.getNombre());
    System.out.println(ej.getFecha());
    //*
    setPrint(); 
    
    }

  public static void set(Ejemplo ej) {
       ej.setNombre("juan perez");
       ej.setFecha("01-01-2021");
   }

   public static void setPrint(){
    Ejemplo ej=new Ejemplo();
    ej.setNombre("carlos perez");
    ej.setFecha("01-02-2021");
    System.out.println(ej.getNombre());
    System.out.println(ej.getFecha());


   }
}
```